# How can I rename variable name for the entire C++ code in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

The title might be vague so here is a part of the code I'm referring to:

```
int main () {                                                        // Line 8
    string jpnum[10] = {"ichi", "nii", "san" , "shi", "go", "roku",  // Line 9
        "shichi", "hachi",                                           // Line 10
        "kyuu", "jyuu"};                                             // Line 11
                                                                     // Line 12
    cout << jpnum[7] << "\n\n";                                      // Line 13
```

When I double click the string jpnum on line 9, it highlights the string for both lines 9 and 13. However, I can only edit/rename the string for line 9.

I want to know what do I click/what shortcut do I type so I can rename them all of them and save me lots of time (especially when the variable is used multiple times throughout the code).

If I right-click it shows a lot of options but I don't think Edit and Folding works. Any thoughts will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try the "Replace in Files" function under the "Search" menu?

Comment: I have a shortcut `Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R` in VS IDE, where it finds all references of the variable and renames them. I am pretty sure there's one in code::blocks too! Although, I personally would use replace all (in files) if that were available. It's usually `Ctrl + Shift + R`

Comment: Thanks M.Kotzjan and kesarling. "Replace in Files" using the Search tab or using the Ctrl+Shift+R shortcut does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double-click on a variable by highlighting it. Then right-click on it, select "Insert\Refactor" => "Rename Symbols", and change the variable name in the window. It will be replaced throughout the code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNTJ8.png)